# error when trying to connect via websocket to the server on Openshift

Tags: java, websocket, openshift, wildfly

My Web-socket server and client are written in Java. When I used a JavaScript web-socket client to connect, there was no issue. When I switched to Java web-socket client, I got the following errors:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.bind(SocketChannelImpl.java:585)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.bind(SocketAdaptor.java:135)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.openTcpStreamConnection(WorkerThread.java:262)
at org.xnio.XnioIoThread.openStreamConnection(XnioIoThread.java:237)
at org.xnio.XnioWorker.openStreamConnection(XnioWorker.java:342)
at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState.doUpgrade(HttpUpgrade.java:247)
at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState.access$100(HttpUpgrade.java:165)
at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade.performUpgrade(HttpUpgrade.java:129)
at io.undertow.websockets.client.WebSocketClient$ConnectionBuilder.connect(WebSocketClient.java:313)
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.connectToServerInternal(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:305)
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.connectToServerInternal(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:299)
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:203)
```

The code was working perfectly on the local-host.

Comment: Are you doing anything differently compared to the JavaScript version, e.g. binding to a different port or IP? Reference to port binding at OpenShift can be found here: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

Comment: @JiriFiala The ports are same in both the versions.